provider error new hashicorp/get provider
terraform plan causes:

Error: Inconsistent dependency lock file
The following dependency selections recorded in the lock file are inconsistent with the current configuration:
provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/get: required by this configuration but no version is selected
To update the locked dependency selections to match a changed configuration, run:
terraform init -upgrade

running terraform init -upgrade gives this error:

Error: Failed to query available provider packages
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/get: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider
named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/get
All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which
modules are currently depending on hashicorp/get, run the following command:
terraform providers

terraform providers gives
provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/get] as one of the providers

What is this provider, and why did it suddenly show up?
Is this a wide hashicorp bug?
I followed the terraform prompts in the console with no success.
Hope you can help
Fixed
It was my fault, the reason was this:
data "get_caller_identity" "current" {}

insted of:
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}


Could you please edit your question and paste the providers configuration? Which version of terraform and the providers are you using?

You probably didn't follow the naming convention for resources properly, that's why terraform is trying to download a provider that doesn't exist.

For backward-compatibility with much older versions of Terraform that didn't yet support automatic installation of third-party providers, Terraform has some heuristics to guess what you meant when you don't declare a provider dependency in your required_providers block:

Any resource block which doesn't have a provider block selects the default instance of whichever provider has the local name matching the first part of the resource type name, up to the first underscore.
If any resource is associated with a provider local name that isn't declared in a required_providers block, Terraform guesses that you intended to use a hashicorp/-namespaced provider with that name because that is how older versions of Terraform (before there were any namespaces at all) would've behaved.

You have written data "get_caller_identity" "current" {}, and so:

Terraform notices that there is no provider argument in this block, and so takes the get prefix from your resource type name and assumes you intended to write provider = get.
There is no get entry in your module's required_providers block, and so Terraform assumes you are trying to use hashicorp/get.

I'm guessing you probably intended to use the aws_caller_identity data source from the hashicorp/aws provider. In that case you will need to spell its type name correctly in your data block:
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

Then the heuristics will work properly:

There is no provider argument, and the resource type name starts with "aws", so Terraform assumes provider = aws.
The required_providers block does not include an entry with the local name aws, and so Terraform guesses that you meant hashicorp/aws.

